# Querying the same table for a list of databases in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This is my first time posting on SO, so please go easy!

I'm attempting to write a SQL script that queries the same table for a list of databases in a single SQL Server instance.

I have successfully queried the list of databases that I required using the following, and inserting this data into a temp table.

```
Select name Into #Versions
From sys.databases
Where name Like 'Master%'
```

`Master` is suffixed with numerical values to identify different environments.

```
Select * From #Versions

Drop Table #Versions
```

The table name I am trying to query, is the same in each of the databases, and I want to extract the newest value from this table and insert it into the `temp` table for each of the database names returned.

I have tried researching this but to no avail. I am fairly comfy with SQL but I fear I could be out of my depth here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following. Once you have the list of your databases, you can build up the query (you need to edit it for your purpose).

```
Select name Into #Versions
From sys.databases
Where name Like 'test%'

declare @sql as varchar(max) = ''
select @sql = @sql + 'INSERT INTO sometable SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ' + name + '..sourcetable ORDER BY somedate DESC; '
FROM #Versions

exec (@sql)

Drop Table #Versions
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [The undocumented sp_MSforeachdb procedure](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx) and [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic393955-145-1.aspx)